# date.php shows all posts. how to fix it?

Tags: categories, pagination, archives, date

I am using the following function for **category.php**.  It's working fine.

```
function cat_page_list(){
/*
post : returns the post for category page
*/  
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $cat1 = get_query_var('cat');
    $cat_name = get_category($cat1)->name;
    $args = array('cat'=> $cat1, 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );        
    query_posts( $args); 
    if(have_posts()) :
        print ('<div class="row">'); 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();   
                $date = explode(",", get_the_time("F,j,Y", "", "", false));
                print(' 
                    <section class="large-4 columns">
                    <section class="main_post cbox1">
                    <section class="post_inner row collapse">');             
                    print('<div class="large-2 columns small-2">
                                <span class="date_format">
                                    <span class="date_num">' . $date[1] . '
                                    </span><br/><span class="date_month">' . substr($date[0], 0, 3) . '
                                    </span></span></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>');
                    print ('<div class="large-10 columns small-10">');
                            the_title('<a class="blogroll_title" href="' . get_permalink() . '"><h1 class="heading_blog">', '</h1></a>');
                    print ('</div>');                                   
                    print ('<!--end post_inner --></section>');
                    print ('<div class="row collapse post_content"><p>');
                        if (strlen(get_the_content()) > 100) {
                            $content = get_the_content();
                            echo str_replace('&nbsp;', '<br /><br />', substr($content, 0, 300)). "....";   
                            echo '</p><a href=" ' . get_permalink() . ' " class="read_more button button_top button_body_col11 button_radius">Read More</a>';
                        }
                        else { the_content(); echo "</p>"; }    
                    print ('<!--end post_content--></div>
                            <section class="post_inner_bottom row collapse">');

                    print('
                    <!--end post_inner_bottom --></section>
                    <!--end main_post cbox1 --></section>                       
                    <!-- end large-4 columns --></section>          
                    <div class="spacer_1px"></div>');
            endwhile;
            if (function_exists("pagination")) {
                pagination();
            }
        print ('<!-- end main row --></div>');
    endif;      
}
```

it's working fine and showing the 3 posts per for peroper categories. Eg: if click the **category 1** and it shows post under **category 1** and  if click the **category 2** and it shows post under **category 2**

Now I want to do the same design on my **date.php**. so I created the function named

```
date_page_list();

and changed the following codes only.

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $cat1 = get_query_var('cat');
    $cat_name = get_category($cat1)->name;
    $args = array('cat'=> $cat1, 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );
```

TO

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );
```

now the problem is when I call the `date_page_list();` it shows all the post from the blog.
How can I fix this.??
Any help will be very much appreciated.

the following code works properly and giving the proper post for the proper dates.
but I need to do the same style as my **category.php**

```
<?php 
$date1 = get_query_var($query_string.'date');
get_posts( array ('posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
<?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?> <br/>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li></br>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a very good look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

You should not need to be creating new queries for these pages.  As near as I can WordPress, has already done the work. You are just doing it over again. That is inefficient.

The only thing that I see that you might need to adjust is the `posts_per_page` argument. You can do that with `pre_get_posts`.

```
add_action(
  'pre_get_posts',
  function($qry) {
    if($qry->is_main_query() && ($qry->is_date() || $qry->is_category())) {
      $qry->set('posts_per_page',3);
    }
  }
);
```

I am also not sure why you need a function for this. The templates themselves should be sufficient. To reuse your formatting code put everything inside the `while` into another file and load it with [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part). Your templates would then look something like this:

```
if(have_posts()) {
  print ('<div class="row">'); 
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    get_template_part('datecatformat'); // loads datecatformat.php
  }
}
```

By reworking things this way, you fix your problem by allowing WordPress to do what it already does pretty well instead of clobbering its queries with your own.

Comment: that `add_action` helped a lot. thank you.. and that efficient way to use the template part also saved file size. is there any way to get some particular part of coding from a php file? eg: if I need to take lines 10 - 25 from **datecatformat.php**, then how can I do that?